# Stop execution while timer is running

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am building a board game using `VB.net`. My problem is that when I have a timer running (for sprite animation) the rest of my program continues executing. Is there some way to delay the execution of the program until the timer has been disabled?

I have tried using `Threading.thread.sleep()` but this only delays the whole process., I assume this is because both the timer and the function that starts it are running on the same thread?

```vb
While nextSpace <> endSpace
            nextSpace += 1
            timerMov.Start()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(timerMov.Interval * 100)
End While

Private Sub mov_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerMov.Tick
        curShip.img.Location = New Point(...)
        If i = 100 Then
            timerMov.Stop()
            i = 0
        End If
        i += 1
    End Sub
```

This results in things occurring before I want them to, i.e the user receives information about the space they have landed on before the animation has completed of them landing on said space.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I think it all depends on how the rest of your code is running, is the progression of your game running on a timer as well? In that case you could suspend that timer. I don't think thread.sleep is ever a good way to go though.

Comment: @AConfusedSimpleton Unfortunately the rest of the game is not running on a timer. Essentially what happens is the timer is started from a while loop inside a subroutine. I want the while loop to wait until the timer has been stopped before looping again.

Comment: One possible simple fix, although not the preferred way of doing it i would say , is to have a boolean `AnimationInProgress` which you set to false when an animation start and to `true`when it finishes. Then in the main progression of the game you can make sure it only progresses when `AnimationInProgress` is `False`

Comment: @AConfusedSimpleton I have actually tried something like this. I had a while loop with  `AnimationInProgress == false` as its condition, although I wasn't sure what to put inside the loop, because having it being empty crashed the program.

Comment: You could consider using `Await Task.Delay(timerMov.interval * 100)` (which will require declaring the containing routine as `Async`) as a way to hold up progress in the main calculation until the animation has finished.  Instead of holding up the whole thread, this will return control to the main message/event loop of the UI thread, which will allow the timer messages to process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Essentially what happens is the timer is started from a while loop
>   inside a subroutine. I want the while loop to wait until the timer has
>   been stopped before looping again.

Get rid of the timer and use [Async/Await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Here is what it'd look like, boiled down to its essence:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' ... possibly more code ...

    While nextSpace <> endSpace
        nextSpace += 1

        For i As Integer = 0 To 100
            Await Task.Delay(someDelayIntervalHere)
            curShip.img.Location = New Point(...)
        Next
    End While

    ' ... possibly more code ...

End Sub
```

Note that the Sub has been marked with `Async` in its declaration line.  Inside the loop the `Await` line causes it to pause (replacing the Tick event of the Timer), but does so in a way that doesn't cause the interface to freeze up.

Comment: I think the timer may still be needed to run the animation, but as I noted in my comment, that would still be compatible with `Await Task.Delay` as the timer events would fire while waiting for the delay to finish.

Comment: @Craig The timer isn't needed as the animation code is now inside the While loop in the inner For loop.  The UI will update and respond correctly while it pauses in the Await line.

Comment: Thanks this was the sort of thing I was looking for :)  thanks, @Craig + @-Idle_Mind